# Create or Clone a smart contract from Binance Smart Chain. Willing to pay some money to learn

Tags: ethereum, cryptocurrency, binance, bitcoin-testnet, binance-smart-chain

Thank you for reading this. I am learning about cryptocurrency and about Binance smart chain. I want to try to learn and want to clone a few projects such as this one:

https://bscscan.com/address/0x359f35085202c8527a0c767557339635a335eb76#code

I am able to deploy the smart contract but when I try to verify and publish, the Contract ABI is empty.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7wcr.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqb06.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj2pg.png)

If someone knows how to create a clone from existing smart contract, I am willing to pay to learn. We can set up a meeting time via Zoom or using TeamViewer and I can pay via Paypal. Please message me if you are interested. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this problem. Thank you everyone! I needed to deploy the main contract and not the parent one.

Comment: Please share if you know, how to copy smart-contract from Binance Smart chain